# Monitoring MySql by C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am currently doing a project about the monitoring of MySQL with C# and I have some problems.

I am preparing to use C# to monitor the changes in Mysql form and there is a dependency libclass in Sqlserver available to achieve this function. But I was supposed to use polling loop to do that and it is a time-consuming process, so I am wondering if there any other method available to process Mysql form to monitor the changes?

Many thanks!
Guo

Comment: Nothing wrong with polling. Do you mean time-consuming as in dev or as in performance? If performance, optimise your DB. If dev - welcome to dev.

Comment: Pooling is often bad if performed too frequently, but every once in a while running a quick script it won't do any bad. BTW, "libclass in Sqlserver" is totally irrelevant for MySql, they're separate RDBMSs.

Comment: What are your requirements, specifically?

Comment: When the database table inserts a new data, I will use a program to process the contents of the table, and this insert data may not be too frequent, I want to be able to be monitored by the program when the data is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to monitor a MySQL instances I might would recommend to use [mysqld_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter), which is designed to do this.

But if I understand correctly you want to monitor changes inside a table?

There are two main option to do that, you can use [audit plugin](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/management/audit_log_plugin.html) , you have to use Enterprise MySQL or Percona Server which is free. You can create almost any kind of filter and log the changes.

The second option is parsing the binary log which is very common it is called `Change Data Capture (CDC)`, a popular application for this is `maxwell`.

You can find more details regarding to this question in this blog post: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/09/13/mysql-cdc-streaming-binary-logs-and-asynchronous-triggers/